# Hypocrisy and Ad Hominem

Tags: logic

I have a little question on logical fallacies and ad hominems. There's this problem:

> Person A and B are both hypocrites; they're both aware of this. Person A argues that B is a hypocrite, and because of that B's words and statements have no merit. Person B counterargues that A is also a hypocrite, and that B's argument based on B being a hyprocrite is hypocrisy in itself, which invalidates A's argument. Is B's logic an ad hominem attack?

I don't think B's using ad hominem (although A might be), since B isn't really attacking A's character but rather A's thought process. Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: Since they're both hypocrites, why are they arguing? They should go bowling instead... they have so much in common.

Comment: ^^ hahaha. B seems be arguing both ad hominem and [tu quoque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque). he's right that A is wrong, but for the wrong reasons (it's because he's arguing ad hominem). unless A is saying that a hypocrite can *never* be right, in which case he's being incoherent, and B is pointing that out, rather than just stating it's ad hominem.

Comment: Did you intend to say, "Person B counterargues that ... **A**'s argument based on B being a hypocrite ..."? As it stands, B is arguing that B's own argument constitutes hypocrisy.